# Teamcity - Combine ldap properties into a single line in ldap-config.properties

Tags: teamcity

I have a teamcity instance connecting to an LDAP server (AD) and I need to configure my VCS user name to be in the following format:

> firstname.surname

I know that I need to modify the following configuration entry in the *ldap-config.properties* file to do this

> teamcity.users.property.plugin:vcs:anyVcs:anyVcsRoot

I know that I need to use the following two ldap properties: givenName, sn.

However, I'm struggling to understand the syntax for doing this in the config. I've tried different combinations, and whilst the properties work on their own, I cannot find a way of concatenating them together. Even the following (which misses out the full stop in the middle) does not work

```
(&(givenName)(sn))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix is to use the following syntax:

```
%ldap.userEntry.%
```

(as per line 160 - 161 in the ldap-config.properties.dist file)

So for my example, where I want firstname then a full stop then the surname, my entire config line would be the following:

```
teamcity.users.property.plugin\:vcs\:anyVcs\:anyVcsRoot=%ldap.userEntry.givenName%.%ldap.userEntry.sn%
```